# Modsecurity oddity

Tags: apache-2.4, debian-wheezy, mod-security

my mod security is loading fine but when I set the server token like so

SecServerSignature "Infodous Webserver" it returns
"Infodous Webserver mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.4.39-0+deb7u1 proxy_html/3.0.1 Server at REDACTED Port 443"

Is it possible to make it say "Infodous Webserver" or "Infodous Webserver Server at REDACTED Port 443"

Answer (score 0):

It is but this is not related to mod_security; rather Apache

Check [ServerTokens](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servertokens) directive and set it to **Prod**

Comment: I tried that and all it did was say Apache

Comment: At the same time you had SecServerSignature set ?

Comment: yes I had had ServerTokens set to Prod and SecServerSignature set

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#SecServerSignature:

> In order for this directive to work, you must set the Apache
>   ServerTokens directive to Full. ModSecurity will overwrite the server
>   signature data held in this memory space with the data set in this
>   directive. If ServerTokens is not set to Full, then the memory space
>   is most likely not large enough to hold the new data we are looking to
>   insert.